# How to display data from all tables in sidebar?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with displaying data from tables, and more accurately displays me a json object.

How can I fix this because I need to display only the titles.

I tried **json_decode**, but throws out an error that a string was expected, an array was passed

**AppServiceProvider:**

```
view()->composer('*', function($view){
$results = [];
$results['zone'] = Zone::all()->last();
$results['tourism'] = Tourism::all()->last();
$results['business'] = Business::all()->last();
$results['culture'] = Culture::all()->last();
$results['education'] = Education::all()->last();
$results['inhabitant'] = Inhabitant::all()->last();
$results['investor'] = Investor::all()->last();
$results['senior'] = Senior::all()->last();
$results['sport'] = Sport::all()->last();
$view->with('sidebar', $results); 
});
```

**Sidebar.blade.php:**

```
@foreach($sidebar as $type => $list)
@include('pages.sidebar-components.'. $type, ['items' => $list])
@endforeach
```

Forexample one sidebar-component view (**Business.blade.php**):

```
{{ $list }}
```

Results:

```
{"id":1,"title":"test","description":"test","path":"dsadsa"}
```

I need:

```
{id:1,title:"test",description:"test",path:"dsadsa"}
```

I've tried to decode json, but I get the error of the expected string, passed array

Answer (score 0):

O my God...

I just removed ->last(); from Sport::all()->last(); and it worked. Solved, to close.